# How does one search for patterns/motifs in folklore or mythology?

Tags: myth-identification, comparative, folkloristics, motifs

I'm currently attempting to research how often a specific type of story (i.e. a motif) occurs in the global corpus of folklore (mythology). For instance, I might be interested in [whether there are examples of powerful figures loosing an eye (other than Odin)](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/853/are-there-any-other-gods-that-permanently-lost-an-eye-other-than-odin). I might also be interested in [whether deities similar to Kali exist in other cultures](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/962/62).

How can I answer these kinds of questions? I obviously don't have time to go read every bit of folklore from every culture in the world. Is there some sort of index, e.g. a [TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/) for folklore, that I could use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before I answer this question, I want to warn the reader. It can be very difficult to compare cultures *correctly*. My advice to anyone who wants to search for patterns (and explain why these patterns exist) is to try learning about a single culture/story first. Once you have shown that you can learn about one culture, then you will have the skills necessary to perform comparisons and learn something from them.

---

Have you heard of the Thompson Motif Index? It's essentially a TVTropes for folklore, i.e. a list of folklore organized by motifs. **Most importantly, it's available for free online.** There are two online versions available: a [difficult to use plain-text tool](https://www.ualberta.ca/~urban/Projects/English/Motif_Index.htm) and [a database version, titled MOMFER, that is easy and convenient to use](http://www.momfer.ml/). Here's a screenshot of MOMFER (which I recommend that you use: it's so much more convenient) in case you are skeptical:

[image: MOMFER Screenshot]

In case you are interested: [the code for MOMFER is available on github](https://github.com/fbkarsdorp/tmi) and [the creators of MOMFER have written a paper about developing the tool](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/0015587X.2015.1006954) (unfortunately behind a paywall).

One issue that might be relevant is that we should not assume that the Thompson Index does not list every instance of a motif (it was published in the 1960s). However, it should be *good enough* for the purposes of the majority of the visitors to this site.

There are [other myth indexes available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motif_%28folkloristics%29#Other_motif_indices) that focus on specific regions and/or are more up to date. As far as I can tell, those indexes aren't available online, so you will have to look for them in a library.