# How do I analyze a mythology?

Tags: folklore, folkloristics, archetypes

[Sorry if this question isn't specific or not very legitimate. I've only been in this site for a while.]

I've been getting into religion and mythology lately. I've been wondering, how do I analyze a mythology? How do I figure out what it's trying to say? How do I figure out what archetypes the myths have?

I have been trying to look up archetypes of mythologies on google (Ex. what archetype is god? What archetype is Zeus? etc).

So any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Hi and welcome on M&F since you have the other SE bonus, I don't think you need the [tour](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/tour). But as you said, your question might be a bit too broad and unspecific. First, I'd like to point out that I'm not really sure what you mean here by archetype. In my understanding it is someone that is a good symbol for many "look-alike" things (eg: Hitler is the archetype of the bad german guy, shouting, harsh, well dressed..)

Comment: So an archetype question in my understanding would be like: How Zeus incarnate the archetype of the all-powerful god (you need to be the archetype of something). Another pointer to understand religions would simply to talk with people who have those beliefs or study them. They are always eager to talk about the beliefs they follow/teach/learn about, eg: [Christianity SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/). Then you can find lots and lots of information on the internet like the Q&A here or more specific websites like [Theoi](https://www.theoi.com/) for the Greek lore.

Comment: Related: [How does one search for patterns/motifs in folklore or mythology?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/how-does-one-search-for-patterns-motifs-in-folklore-or-mythology)